# Why are some questions faded?

Tags: support, question-lists

I posted a question that had a white filter over it. Basically, it still appears on the "newest" questions, and is still clickable, but has a white filter over it, such that it's barely visible. Can anyone explain this phenomenon?

The question, btw, is NOT on hold, and rather has 2 up-votes as of now. I don't know if anyone else can see it as faded too. I would post an image, but my rep is too low. Remember, this is happening on the newest questions category only, not the question itself.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291359/559745)? Then it's because of your ignored tags.

Comment: Have you hidden any tags on that site?

Comment: @Flo - doesn't asking a question in a tag automatically remove it from your ignored tags? I'm pretty sure that happened with Star Wars on SFF for me.

Comment: FYI low scores make questions disappear entirely, and being on hold just adds [on hold] to the title. Only ignored tags cause the fading.

Comment: @Mith no, I don't think so, at least I never observed that.